Кортежи: возможные типы
В .NET кортежи - значимые типы, читал информацию про них в очередной книге, и обнаружил, что в прошлом коде, будучи совсем новичком, использовал в кортежах ссылочные переменные. И там всё работает. Как такое возможно?  Это код для API, который обязан писаться в версии Framework 4.8. Может ранее в кортежи можно было помещать всё что угодно?
Для уточнения, возвращал из методов не просто ссылочные типы, но и даже списки ссылок. Что-то вроде этого:
public (List<SomeType>, List<List<SomeType2>>) Method() 
{    }

Почему код допустил использование в кортежах ссылочных типов?

Конкретно вопрос то в чем?

Неясно, поччему вы решили, что в кортежах запрещено использование ссылочных типов.

Объект ссылочного типа может занимать в куче любой объем. Но вот размер ссылки на него имеет фиксированный размер. Поэтому ссылка может без проблем располагаться на стеке, в структурах и так далее.

Решил, что в кортежах не используются ссылочные типы, потому что в любом издании все примеры про примитивные типы, ни одного (повторюсь, ни одного) нет про ссылочный. Не так много книг я, конечно, читал, но из имеющихся, включая Рихтера, включая документацию майкрософт - ни слова об этом. Буду признателен, если скажете авторитетный источник, который опровергает мною сказанное.
Если, например, я читаю про структуры, там четко и ясно сказано, что они могут содержать переменные ссылочного типа и все вытекающие из этого последствия... Про кортежи об этом ни слова

Кортеж, это синтаксический сахар, не более... Посмотрите на то как реализован любой тип Tuple https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src%2Flibraries%2FSystem.Private.CoreLib%2Fsrc%2FSystem%2FValueTuple.cs

У вас путаница между самим кортежем и его элементами:

Сам кортеж - значимый тип, т.е. он хранится сразу в памяти, в отличие от ссылочных типов, для которых сначала создаётся объект где-нибудь в куче, а потом берётся ссылка на этот объект, и уже эта ссылка отправляется куда-то. Поэтому кортежи используют, например, для возврата из функций - так работает быстрее, чем с объектами, которые сначала создаются, а потом из функции возвращается ссылка на объект. В случае кортежа из функции возвращается сразу сам кортеж.
Элементы кортежа могут быть любого типа. Хотите - значимого, хотите - ссылочного, ограничений нет.

P.S. Ссылка на официальную документацию. Цитата:

Tuple types are value types; tuple elements are public fields. That makes tuples mutable value types.


Спасибо большое за ответ!
Выше уже ответил, повторюсь, и даже, наверное, более кратко. Где я могу посмотреть утверждение, что "Элементы кортежа могут быть любого типа". Какая-то документация, книга...
Взяв ключевое слово ref или out, я найду много подтверждений, об использовании с ссылочными типами, значимыми типами, со всякими исключительными интересными ситуациями. Заглянув в тему кортежей, я вижу лишь куча примеров на (int, double), (decimal,int, int) и т.д., но ни слова про переменные классов

@iDanilov: Ну вот вам доказательство. Компилируется же?

@iDanilov Насколько я понял, примеры везде приведены с простыми типами потому, что иначе весь смысл использования кортежей пропадает. Если вы уже используете классы, то вам проще создать класс - надстройку над другими классами, и возвращать его из функции, например. Кортеж удобен и, возможно, полезен для скорости работы, именно когда вам нужно куда-то передать именно простые типы, вы их тогда просто заворачиваете в кортеж и получаете два в одном - простоту использования и быстроту работы.
